# Is using snap and using "move to trash" mutually exclusive when using home directories on alternative partitions

Tags: mount, snap, symbolic-link, trash, bind

I slowly started to accept that Ubuntu is forcing its users to use snap instead of apt (which I've used for 20+ years and like). Having been around for a few years, I'm offloading my home directories to an alternative partition, as this greatly facilitates system upgrades and backups. Symlinking them into /home has never been an issue -- well, until snap came along.

If I understand it correctly, then snap does not allow for home directories to be symlinks, but requires them to be mounted (-bind).

I could live with this, if it wouldn't break other things - but deleting objects to trash in directories mounted directories does not seem to work, as "rename doesn't cross mount points" ( https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=70831 ).

Does anybody know a solution to this issue, I can't be the only one having it? Do I have to go back to apt and drop snap (I do actually like having the safety net of a trash)?

TIA

-- t

Comment: So this still does not work when you have mount-bind your entire home directory elsewhere? Because then, the data to delete and the trash continue to live on the same partition, I would have expected that would continue to work.

Comment: It does, now, thanks for the comment. It was a bit more tricky, I've had several folders in home linked to yet other partitions for historical reasons and network drives. I guess I'll have to live with the fact that for those that have to remain I'll have to live without a trash.